# Simple HTML form to pass values to URL

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, url

I have a simple HTML form with a `select` element. The purpose is this is to use Wordpress's built in query parameters to allow users to sort the posts in an archive. Date Added, Title, etc.

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
    <label id="sortLabel" for="orderby">Sort Songs:</label>
        <select name="orderby" id="sortbox">
            <option disabled selected>Sort by:</option>
            <option value="date&order=asc">Oldest First</option>
            <option value="date&order=dsc">Newest First</option>
            <option value="title&order=asc">Alphabetical (A-Z)</option>
            <option value="title&order=dsc">Alphabetical (Z-A</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

The `option` values are being passed through to the URL fine, but the URLs are encoding, causing the URL to look like this:

`www.example.com/songs/?orderby=date%26order%3Dasc`

Instead of this:

`www.example.com/songs/?orderby=date&order=asc`

Comment: See [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)?

Comment: Thanks for that @JosefZ, I guess my problem is how do I get the browser to do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is simply how HTML forms work.

The `value` attributes are *arbitrary text*. The browser is sending the form request to `www.example.com/songs/?orderby=<value>`, where you happen to be setting the `<value>` to `"date&order=asc"`, `"date&order=dsc"`, etc.

The `orderby`'s value has to make it to the server intact. `&` and `=` are reserved characters in a URL's query component, so that is why they are being percent-encoded when the `orderby` field is added to the URL query, thus allowing the server to properly receive the `<value>` that the user selected for `orderby` in the HTML.

To do what you want, you need to treat `orderby` and `order` separately in the HTML. I would add a separate `<select>` for `order`, eg:

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
    <label id="sortLabel" for="orderby">Sort Songs:</label>
    <select name="orderby" id="sortbox">
        <option disabled selected>Sort by:</option>
        <option value="date">Date</option>
        <option value="title">Title</option>
    </select>
    <select name="order" id="sortbox">
        <option disabled selected>Order by:</option>
        <option value="asc">Oldest First, Alphabetical (A-Z)</option>
        <option value="dsc">Newest First, Alphabetical (Z-A)</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

If you wanted to make the `order` list a little cleaner, you could use client-side scripting to manipulate the display texts of the `order` options whenever the user selects a different `orderby` option.